# If $f$ is an integral flow in $G$, then why there is a feasible acyclic integral flow of the same value?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, network, network-flow

I have already proven that this statement (a) given any feasible flow $f$ in $G$, there is a feasible acyclic flow of the same value. But I am not sure why the following statement(b) is true: If $f$ is an integral flow in $G$, then there is a feasible acyclic integral flow of the same value.

Isn't the statement (b) just trivial from the statement (a)? Since we have a feasible flow $f$ of integer flow value in $G$, and by (a), there is a feasible acyclic flow of the same value, which is also an integer. What nontrivial points am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just imitate the proof for the general case.  In that proof, you reduce the flows in any directed cycle, all of whose edges have positive flow, by the flow in the cycle edge with minimum flow, until no positive cycles remain.  If the original flow is integral, this process preserves integrality.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this process preserves integrality? The flow along a given edge, f(e), is not necessarily an integer, and the minimum flow cycle edge(the bottleneck)is also not necessarily an integer. How can you prove that if the original flow is integral, removing these flow values still preserves the integrality?

Comment: @KingHo Isn't $f$ an integral flow?  Doesn't that mean the flow in every edge is an integer?  If not, what is an integral flow?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I got the definition wrong, the name are quite confusing.  At first, I thought integral flow just means a flow of integer value instead of the flow in every edge is an integer. Well, then in this case(flow in every edge is an integer), since subtracting integer from integer remains an integer, so it preserves the integrality.

Comment: Ah, things make more sense now.